# jQuery insert new line outside html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to insert new html after another with 'newline' outside the html tag. But it's not working when I do it this way :

```
$('\n<span>Banana</span>').insertAfter(word);
```

But when I put `\n` inside the span tag it's working:

```
$('<span>\nBanana</span>').insertAfter(word);
```

I want to put `\n` outside the span tag when inserting a new span. Please help me. Thank you. ^^

```js
var word = $('pre span.active');

$('#a').on('click', function () {
  if($(word).next('span').length){
    // below is not working
    $('\n<span>Banana</span>').insertAfter(word);
    
    $(word).next().addClass('active');
    $(word).removeClass('active');
  }
})

// but when I use \n inside span tag is working
//$('<span>\nBanana</span>').insertAfter(word);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
<span>Apple</span> <span class="active">Papaya</span> <span>Avocado</span>
</pre>
<button id="a">Next</button>
```

**EDIT**
Based on Dinesh answer, I use `display:block` inside span tag : `$('\n<span style="display:block;">Banana</span>').insertAfter(word);` and it's working. is this a good way? or we have another solution for not using css?

Comment: did u try ``<div>\n</div><span>Banana</span>`` ??

Comment: thanks for response. I don't want to add another html tag, span only :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<br>` tag instead `\n`

```js
var word = $('span');
$('\n<span>Banana</span>').insertAfter(word);
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre><span>Apple</span></pre>
```

Update: OP wants without any tag. 
make span tag `display:block` using css

Comment: thank you for answer, but I don't want to add another html tag except span  :(

Comment: i done with css now. please check now. without any tag

Comment: thank you for helping me, but I have question, there is '\n' with it? I really need to add '\n' for parsing purpose

Comment: still you can add \n

Comment: keep your html with display:block and add your \n to html

Comment: Dinesh I really thank you for your help :) I just update my snippet, and I think use display:block is great solution but I need to keep layout 'word after word - line by line' not 'word per line'. I use display:block and then word separately by new line, for example when I click button (test case) new span will created and automatically add new line

Comment: I'm sorry if I have too much question - dinesh

Comment: I use display:block inside span tag : $('\n<span style="display:block;">Banana</span>').insertAfter(word); and it's working. is this a good way? or we have another solution for not using css?

Comment: I need to replace \n globally with square bracket [] and add something inside it.

Comment: yes thank you dinesh, but I don't know why my heart still doubt for using css as a solution for this case. I mean I have spent hours and still not find 'satisfying' solution :(

Comment: css is good to use. but i suggest you to rethink on usage of \n in html and parsing. it doen't seem to be good way to have \n in html and parsing it later.

Comment: that's the point. I need to keep layout as it goes while later still need to parsing a very complex text. But so far using display:block is great solution. I will rethink to use \n in html as you said. Thank you very much for your answers. :)